# React Native The Development Server return response error 500.

Tags: react-native

[image: Error 500]

I don't know what's it an error but I make sure my code that correct.
Sometimes, it's working but sometimes it's not working.

So how to fix this problem? 
Please help!

Comment: share your package,json file also

Comment: {
  "name": "TestProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
    "jest": "23.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Comment: how are you starting the project? ..`npm run ios` is the node server is open by doing that?

Comment: No sir, I starting my project : react-native run-android

Comment: What is the error on your node environment?...did you import `flatlist` where you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

The screen has answered itself. It is related to the module you use. Go check that "inspector" module homepage. Maybe it is not compatible with react-native version you use.

Answer (score 0):

Close all terminals and processes and then execute first `react-native start` and then execute `react-native run-android`.